# Jquery Cycle - go to new URL at the end of cycle

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Is there a way to make the last slide's next arrow link to a new page?

I've been trying to use this code as a starting point http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/end.html but I don't seem to be getting anywhere when combined with captions.

Edit: unlike this example, I would like to have the End function work without the timed scrolling. Ie timeout: 0 so that you have to manually advance each slide. Upon the last slide it goes to a new URL. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YFyKg/5/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    nowrap: false,
    timeout: 0,
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    next: '.next',
    prev: '.prev',
    after: onAfter,
    onPrevNextEvent: function(isNext, zeroBasedSlideIndex) { 
        if(isNext && zeroBasedSlideIndex == 0)
        {
        document.location = 'http://www.google.ca';   
        }
    }
});
function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {
var caption = (opts.currSlide + 1) + ' / ' + opts.slideCount;
$('#caption').html(caption); }
});
```

Comment: thanks I'll have a jsfiddle page ready once I'm back later today - thanks in advance

Comment: jValdron thank you again - I tried it here but doesn't seem to work - perhaps I have entered your code incorrectly? http://jsfiddle.net/YFyKg/8/

Comment: I tried it using jsFiddle, but it doesn't seem to allow document.location to be changed. Just put an alert in there to see if it works :)

Comment: Here is a new url: http://jsfiddle.net/YFyKg/10/ thanks again jValdron - it doesn't seem to work for me but super I'm appreciative of your efforts, thank you

Comment: jValdron, this is brilliant - the new url wasn't working in jsfiddle but does work perfectly - THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    fx:      'scrollHorz', 
    timeout:  2000, 
    autostop: 1, 
    end:      function() {  
        window.location="next_page.php";
    } 
});
```

Comment: my apologies, I should have been more clear - I would like it to be manually paged and not automated as in these examples with timeout: 0

Comment: @Chumtarou I saw your jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/YFyKg/9/
that will never work with jsfiddle  because it uses Frames to dispaly the result of your code and your browser will block the redirect code with error message (you can see it if you open the console) ::
"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://jsfiddle.net/YFyKg/9/ from frame with URL http://jsfiddle.net/YFyKg/9/. Domains, protocols and ports must match."
so try it on your server or locally it will work for sure

Comment: Thank you Ayman - your code with timeout: x value works great - however, I apologize that I was not clear that I was needing timeout: 0 where it doesn't work unfortunately. Thank you again!